# show all the posts made by the logged in user

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.5

laravel 5.5 
voyager 1.0

I need to go into a table and retrieve all the posts made by the logged in used. 
I'm using **laravel Auth** to take care of login.
At the moment i have:

controller:

```
public function index(){
   $datum = ReportDatum::paginate(5);
   return view('pages.feed', ['datum' => $datum]);
}
```

model:

```
class ReportDatum extends Model {
   public function owner(){
     return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'owner_id'); 
   }
}
```

and in the view

```
@foreach ($datum as $data) 
    <h5>{{ $data->owner->name }}</h5>
    <h3>{{ $data->title }}</h3>
    <p>{{ $data->description }}</p>
    <p>{{ $data->created_at->format('d M Y') }}</p>
@endforeach
    {{ $datum->render() }}
```

So far this retrieves all the data. I need to limit it to just the table entries where the logged in users **id** = **owner_id**  How can I achieve this this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your User.php file (Model) add a new method as below.

```
public function datum()
{
  return $this->hasMany(ReportDatum::class, 'owner_id', 'id');
}
```

after implementing that method, go to your controller and change what ever you have with this code to get ReportDatum belongs to a logged in user.

```
$reportDatums = Auth::user()->datum;
```

then in your view do something like this.

```
@foreach ($reportDatums as $datum)
   <h5>{!! $datum->name !!}</h5>
   {-- rest of your data here --}
@endforeach
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: When using this method the view doesn't load. When changing how the routes work to get the view back it breaks my login wall and gives a   "Undefined variable: reportDatums"